# Proving statements with the definition of functions.

Tags: functions

I'm a bit stuck proving questions such as "$S\circ R$ is a function if $R$ and $S$ are both functions." Is this a case of stating the definition of a composite function?

Thanks.

Would the following proof be correct?

$$
\forall x \in X. \exists y \in Y. (x,y)\in R  
$$

$$
\forall y \in Y. \exists z\in Z. (y,z)\in S
$$

$$
\therefore \forall x \in X. \exists z \in Z. (x,z) \in S\circ R
$$

Comment: Yes. Did you try doing that?

Comment: You might also state the definition of an ordinary function, and then show that the composite function satifies that definition

Comment: I think so, I just not sure what the actual proof should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A binary relation $R\subset X\times Y$ can be classified as a *function*
if it suffices:

> $\forall x\in X\;\exists!y\in Y\;\left(x,y\right)\in R$

(in words: for every $x\in X$ there is **exactly one** $y\in Y$ such
that $\left(x,y\right)\in R$).

This unique $y$ is denoted as $R(y)$. Now let $S\subset Y\times Z$ be a binary relation and define $S\circ R$ by:

> $\left(x,z\right)\in S\circ R$ iff $\left(x,y\right)\in R\wedge\left(y,z\right)\in S$
>   for some $y\in Y$.

It can be proved that $S\circ R$ is a function
if $S$ and $R$ are functions. Starting with $x\in X$ there is a
unique $y\in Y$ with $\left(x,y\right)\in R$ (this because $R$
is a function). For this unique $y$ there is a unique $z\in Z$ with
$\left(y,z\right)\in S$ (this because $S$ is a function). Then $\left(x,z\right)\in S\circ R$ and $z\in Z$ is unique. Here $S\circ R$ is the composite function and $z=S\circ R(x)=S(R(x))=S(y)$.

**Warning1**: Sometimes $S\circ R$ is denoted as $R\circ S$

**Warning2**: Actually functions are often defined as triples $f=\left(X,G,Y\right)$
where $G\subset X\times Y$ is a binary relation having the mentioned property.
Here $X$ is the domain, $Y$ is the codomain and
$G$ is the graph of $f$.

Comment: Would this proof be correct?

$$
\forall x \in X. \exists y \in Y. (x,y)\in R  
$$

$$
\forall y \in Y. \exists z\in Z. (y,z)\in S
$$

$$
\therefore \forall x \in X. \exists z \in Z. (x,z) \in S\circ R

$$

Comment: That is correct reasoning. But what exactly are you trying to prove here? You are not proving that $S\circ R$ is a function here, because the fact that $z$ is unique is *not* proved. $\exists$ should be changed into $\exists!$ for that.

Comment: I am trying to prove S∘R is a function. How would I prove that z is unique?

Comment: As I said: $\exists$ should be changed into $\exists!$ In words: for every $x\in X$ there is a *unique* $y\in Y$ s.t..... and for every $y\in Y$ there is a *unique* $z\in Z$ s.t.... so for every $x\in X$ there is a *unique* $z\in Z$ s.t....

Comment: I see, I wasn't aware of the there exists uniquely notation. It makes more sense now. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I assume that here $R$ and $S$ are binary relations (why else would anyone use uppercase variable names for functions? ;) ). So you would have to look up the definition of a binary relation, $S\circ R$ for binary relations $R$ and $S$, and the definition of a function as a special kind of binary relation.

Of course, I only guessed the context, it may be different.